# Flex elements don't work. How can i fix my code to solve that problem?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why can't I use `justify-content:` `space-between` or `space-around`?

```css
.mobile-page-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.mobile-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-page-wrapper">
  <div class="mobile-nav">
    <img src="./img/mobile-nav-logo.svg" alt="LOGO" class="logo-mobile">
    <ul class="mobile-soc">
      <li><img class="mobile-fb" src="./img/Facebook.svg" alt="Facebook"></li>
      <li><img class="mobile-vk" src="./img/VK.svg" alt="Vk"></li>
      <li><img class="mobile-inst" src="./img/Instagram.svg" alt="Instagram"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.mobile-nav -->
  <div class="main-idea-mobile">
    <h1>SSDSDSDS<br>DASDASD</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- /.main-idea-mobile -->

</div>
<!-- /.mobile-page-wrapper -->
```

I would like to use `justify-content: space-between;` with `flex-direction: column` but it doesn't work. Plz help me to solve that problem.

Comment: You need to set a height on the wrapper

Comment: Welcome to SO! What actually you want to set in this layout?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish for there to be more space between the items in mobile-wrapper you need to set its height property.

`display: flex; justify-items: space-between;` seems to be working on mobile-nav because mobile-nav is a div which is a block level element and therefore has a default width of 100%, and the default flex-direction is row.

I have attached your snippet below with the height of mobile-wrapper set to 100vh as an example.

```css
.mobile-page-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100vh;
}

.mobile-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-page-wrapper">
  <div class="mobile-nav">
    <img src="./img/mobile-nav-logo.svg" alt="LOGO" class="logo-mobile">
    <ul class="mobile-soc">
      <li><img class="mobile-fb" src="./img/Facebook.svg" alt="Facebook"></li>
      <li><img class="mobile-vk" src="./img/VK.svg" alt="Vk"></li>
      <li><img class="mobile-inst" src="./img/Instagram.svg" alt="Instagram"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.mobile-nav -->
  <div class="main-idea-mobile">
    <h1>SSDSDSDS<br>DASDASD</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- /.main-idea-mobile -->

</div>
<!-- /.mobile-page-wrapper -->
```

(I noticed that when running the snippets from your post and my answer they look the same in the small window, you can see the difference if you click full page)